# Opencv merge just give black screen(python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm studying opencv. I want to change rgb with certain process and merge it again. My code so far just gives me black screen. As you see I check rgb by printing it and it does not think that gives black screen.

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  

img= cv2.imread( 'img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
img=cv2.resize(img,(400,300))
b=img[:,:,0]
g=img[:,:,1]
r=img[:,:,2]
b1,g1,r1=b,g,r


r=r1*0.012+g1*0.0885+b1*-2.0e-04
g=1.12e-01*r1+8.89e-01*g1+1.55e-04*b1
b=r1*4.53e-03+g1*1.30e-04+b1

r=np.array(r,dtype=np.int64)
g=np.array(g,dtype=np.int64)
b=np.array(b,dtype=np.int64)

print(r)
print(g)
print(b)

img_F=cv2.merge((b,g,r))
cv2.imshow('Eya',img_F)


cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I think its an issue of data-type. Unless you intentionally want the data-type to be `np.int64`, you should set the type to `np.uint8`.

Comment: @sgarizvi thank you, after change the type to uint8, it works. I thought that rgb use 'int' type but maybe there's something else process that I don't know.

Comment: @남김대연... OpenCV reads images as type `uint8` by default.